# Javascript Type Error: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions

Tags: javascript, arrays, bigint

I was trying to add a individual digits of an BigInt number to an array. When I did that I encountered the above error.

```
Below is the code Snippet:
var plusOne = function(digits) {
    const outputValue = BigInt(digits.join("")) + 1n;
    let arr = [];
    while(outputValue > 0)
    {
        arr.push(BigInt(outputValue%10));
        outputValue = BigInt(Math.floor(outputValue/10));
    }
    return arr;
};
  

  console.log(plusOne([6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]));
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

I tried making the push into the array as a BigInt but it never worked. I want to add the individual digits to the array from the BigInt Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you wanted:

```
var plusOne = function(digits) {
    let outputValue = BigInt(digits.join("")) + 1n; // changed const to let
    let arr = [];
    while(outputValue > 0)
    {
        arr.push(BigInt(outputValue%10n)); // changed 10 to 10n 
        outputValue = BigInt(outputValue/10n); // changed 10 to 10n and removed Math.Floor
    }
    return arr;
};
console.log(plusOne([6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]));
```

First of all you need to use x%10n and x/10n when working with BigInt numbers (essentially suffix the values with an `n`)

Secondly you dont need to use Math.Floor on this operation and it also wont work as BigInts can not be converted to a number. Read more about it in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66192167/how-to-math-floor-on-bigint-in-javascript)

Lastly you need to declare the outputValue with `let` because you are modifying its value later

Comment: Thank you this helped, I missed the 10n in order to represent BigInt numbers